# mouse middle click opens dash in 13.04, regardless of application

Tags: mouse, logitech

does anyone know how to change the behavior of my mouse middle-click button?  it always opens the dash no matter what application i am in.  it's a wireless logitech t400 if that matters.  thanks.

Comment: Have you read [Windows 7 actions](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/mice-pointers/articles/win7-t400-actions)? It looks like a tap opens the Start Menu (for Windows), possibly Ubuntu thinks you are pressing the Super key.

Comment: Same issue here. When I tested the input of the lower middle button (using `xinput --test id#`) it showed: key press 133 It sends a keyboard key and not a mouse button click :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As edwin noted in his comment, the middle mouse button of your Logitech Zone Touch T400 wireless mouse has an unusual default behavior. In fact there are two different middle mouse button behaviors, one for the upper and center part of the middle button (your problem middle mouse behavior) and another one for the bottom of the middle mouse button.

However the mouse behavior can be changed using `xinput`. Open the terminal and type `xinput`. The output of running `xinput` will tell you the full device name and the device id of your Logitech Zone Touch T400 wireless mouse. All you need to note from running this command is the device id number of your mouse. In the commands that follow, I'll call the mouse id number **id#**. In the commands that follow, substitute your mouse id number for id#.

To display the mouse properties run:

```
xinput list-props id#
```

Find the display property called `Button Labels`. Read the whole line of the display property called `Button Labels` to find out what each mouse button of your mouse does. Next you need to display the list of digits corresponding to each Button Label. To do this run:

```
xinput get-button-map id#
```

Next you can switch the mouse actions by switching the numbers around that you got from running `xinput get-button-map id#`. Let's say you have 12 mouse actions and you want to switch mouse action 11 with mouse action 12. To do this run:

```
xinput set-button-map id# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 11
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't think the button on the T400 that calls the dash (or the overview in Gnome, or the start menu in Windows) can be remapped.  It seems to send the "Super" keyboard button signal to the system.  I attempted to remap every button [all 24 according to 'xinput get-button-map'] on the mouse to do a right-click, but still the middle button brings up the overview/dash.

Comment: Yeah - I ran `xev` and clicked all the buttons - the top middle one doesn't seem to show a button number like the others...

Answer (score 1):

You can remap the "Super_L" (keycode 133) to button_2 (middle button) by the following method:

http://linuxaleph.blogspot.com/2008/11/mapping-middle-click-to-keyboard-key.html

Answer (score 0):

I have this mouse, the only 'fix' I was able to come up with is the "emulate middle click by clicking both left and right buttons" in the "Mouse and touchpad" 'zone' in settings.
Not the best solution, but it works for me.