# Remap the middle click action of Logitech T400 wireless mouse

Tags: xorg, xinput

I want to remap the functionality of the front part of middle click and back part of middle click on the Logitech Zone Touch Mouse T400 model.

According to the answer in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330754/mouse-middle-click-opens-dash-in-13-04-regardless-of-application) question, I tried the commands but I don't understand what to exactly swap.

Here is the output for the command `xinput list-props id#` (10 being the device id)

```
 nirmik@nirmik:~$ xinput list-props 10
Device 'Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4026':
    Device Enabled (134):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (136): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (256): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (257):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (258):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (259):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (251):    1133, 50475
    Device Node (252):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (653): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (655):  0
    Axis Labels (656):  "Rel X" (144), "Rel Y" (145), "Rel Horiz Wheel" (650), "Rel Dial" (651), "Rel Vert Wheel" (652)
    Button Labels (657):    "Button Left" (137), "Button Middle" (138), "Button Right" (139), "Button Wheel Up" (140), "Button Wheel Down" (141), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (142), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (143), "Button Side" (645), "Button Extra" (646), "Button Forward" (647), "Button Back" (648), "Button Task" (649), "Button Unknown" (643), "Button Unknown" (643), "Button Unknown" (643), "Button Unknown" (643), "Button Unknown" (643), "Button Unknown" (643), "Button Unknown" (643), "Button Unknown" (643), "Button Unknown" (643), "Button Unknown" (643), "Button Unknown" (643), "Button Unknown" (643)
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (658):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (659):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (660): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (661): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (662):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (663):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (664):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (665):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (666):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (667):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (668): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (669):  0
```

And the output of the next command `xinput get-button-map 10` is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

Now what do I exactly swap to change the middle click to front part of middle click = middle click action. From/instead of front part of middle click = super button

Comment: The comment on [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/342713/15341) seems to suggest you can't change it... otherwise I'd suggest swapping 2 and 10.

Comment: Run `xev | grep -i "button"` in a terminal. Move to the window, click the buttons you wanna swap. Please add the output from the terminal to your question.

Comment: `xev | grep i "button"` doesn't work fro T400 middle-front button. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Try imwheel.

```
sudo apt-get install imwheel
```

You can configure your buttons using imwheel and it's recommended by the Ubuntu wiki.

Answer (score 2):

I used this way:

1. Install `xbindkeys` and `xdotool`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xdotool
   ```
2. Rebind the <kbd>Super</kbd> key to middle mouse button by `xbindkeys` config

   ```
   $ cat ~/.xbindkeysrc
   "xdotool click 2"
     c:133
   ```
3. Add `xbindkeys` to start with `X`

   ```
   $ echo xbindkeys > ~/.xinitrc
   ```
4. Disable opening Dash on <kbd>Super</kbd> key

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```

   Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `about:config`

   On tab "Launcher" you can disable or change "Key to show the Dash..."
5. Start `xbindkeys` for this session or reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will really help, since I can't try it.  If it works, let me know.

If you're running 12.04, you can use [btnx](http://linuxappfinder.com/package/btnx).  It will ask for the btnx-config, which you can get [here](http://ftp.univ-nantes.fr/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/btnx-config/?order=s)

You can also change the button mapping with xmodmap. For instance, to swap the left with the right mouse button:

```
xmodmap -e 'pointer = 3 2 1'
```

To revert it, simply set 1 2 3 or use 'default' according to the [manpage](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/xmodmap.1.html).

You may also take a look at [How to configure extra mouse buttons in Ubuntu 13.10](http://richardbrucebaxter.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-configure-extra-mouse-buttons-in.html) for more info.