# Remap Logitech T400 middle click

Tags: mouse, logitech, remapping

I have a Logitech T400. This mouse has two "middle click buttons":

[image]

Button *A* is mapped to the regular middle click, which is what I want. But button *B* is mapped to *Super L* which is useless, I want to map it also to the regular middle click too. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

I looked into [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432228/remap-the-middle-click-action-of-logitech-t400-wireless-mouse) of someone asking the same. None of the answers worked for me. I also tried

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 133 = Pointer_Button2"
```

as suggested [here](http://linuxaleph.blogspot.com/2008/11/mapping-middle-click-to-keyboard-key.html) which also did not worked and I lost the real *Super L* button in the keyboard which I would like to conserve.

I have tried with the application [Input Remapper](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper) with this configuration:
[image]
and it works as I want, but it breaks the soft scroll of the mouse so it is not a solution to me.

If I run `xev` then one click and release of button *A* produces this:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    root 0x7b2, subw 0x0, time 886786, (68,93), root:(939,1634),
    state 0x0, button 2, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    root 0x7b2, subw 0x0, time 887362, (68,93), root:(939,1634),
    state 0x200, button 2, same_screen YES
```

and one click and release of button *B* produces this:

```
MappingNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    root 0x7b2, subw 0x0, time 893980, (68,93), root:(939,1634),
    state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x5e00001,
    root 0x7b2, subw 0x0, time 894604, (68,93), root:(939,1634),
    state 0x40, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

How can I remap button *B* to "regular middle click" and (if possible) keep *Super L* working in my keyboard? If no extra apps/programs have to be installed for such simple task, better.

Comment: Try installing `Solaar`. It may allow you to customize the buttons.

Comment: I am already using it for the smooth scroll. But cannot find anything to remap buttons.

Comment: What version of `Solaar` do you have installed?

Comment: 1.1.1 (characters so Stack Overflow lets me comment)

Comment: That's the current version alright. I don't understand what you mean with the rest of your comment.

Comment: Do you have Windows installed?

Comment: No, no access to Windows for the moment.

Comment: What does *"characters so Stack Overflow lets me comment"* mean?

Comment: That was because there is a minimum length to post a comment, just added stuff to overcome such minimum.

Comment: Check out `imwheel`. In Synaptic or at http://imwheel.sourceforge.net/. Maybe it'll help.