# Map mouse button to right click

Tags: xorg, mouse

I'm looking for a way to map a mouse button to simulate the right click (contextual menu) in Ubuntu 13.10. In windows I can achieve this with AutoHotKey in an easy way, just by adding this line

```
(XButton2::LButton)
```

to the script file.

By executing `xev` in the terminal, I know that the physical button of my mouse is detected with `id=11`. I wonder if there is a way in Ubuntu to map `button:id=11` to `button:id=3`, or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330754/mouse-middle-click-opens-dash-in-13-04-regardless-of-application/330770#330770), find the buttons that should be switched. If 11 and 3 need to be switched, you switch them in the sequence like this:

```
xinput set-button-map id# 1 2 11 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 3 12
```

If this works, you need to make it run automatically. As explained in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270049/how-to-run-a-command-at-login), you can add the command to the end of `~/.profile` (in your home directory) to make it run when you log in.